# Find amount of IO occurring over various NFS mounts

Tags: linux, nfs, io

When I run `netstat | grep nfs`, I get the currently mounted `nfs` connections for a given host in a cluster. If there is massive `io` happening over 1 (or 2) of the connections, how can I monitor this? Is there a way I can print out *both* which `nfs` connections are mounted *and* the amount of traffic over said `nfs` mounts?

Comment: Have you had a look at `nfsiostat`?